# Want to load a page when downloads complete using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, download

I have a controller :-

```
function game_file($filename)
    {      
        $file_path = base_url()."resources/games_application/$filename";
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file_path);
        redirect('downloads');  //This is not working 
    }
```

My view is :-

```
<a href='".base_url()."downloads/game_file/".$games_data['file_name']."'>Download<a/>
```

I can download a file but the problem is after downloading I want to redirect to `download` controller. This only downloads my file but does not redirects after the download is complete. Am I am doing anything wrong?

EDIT :-
I know I cannot redirect because header is already sent ,so can anyone please help me on this what will be the solution?

Answer (score 2):

What you are proposing will **NEVER** work. as a `redirect()` is a header action, and you've already SET headers.  But that is just one issue in itself.

You cannot setup a **download** of a file, then redirect the page to somewhere else! Need to re-think your process. Maybe do a javascript catch of the 'download' action from the main download page.

but ya... `redirect('downloads');  //This is not working` will never work.